# Zend-PDF error: Can not open file for writing

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, zend-framework, zend-pdf

I am using ZendFramwork1, my local sever php 5.4. and with MongoDB .I have use function `Zend_Pdf` to draw PDF in my project. it's run well in my local server. but when i put code to  sever that have same version PHP. Everything module is okay but for function print data to pdf  is errors . I got message like `PDF error: Can not open 'data/reports/myfile.pdf' file for writing.` . Any one can help me . what's different between my local server and real sever ?

I am looking to see your reply soon. 
thank

Comment: Check the data/reports/ folder and make sure it's writeable by the user that apache is running as.

Comment: it's relate to folder permission ?

Comment: it sounds like it, as the error is saying it couldn't open that file for writing - if you have ftp access, make sure the /data/reports/ folder exists and run a chmod 777 command on that folder, then try the script again.

Comment: may be not this problem , because i check permission of it already is full permission. and i try 'chmod 7777'

Comment: I should have also suggested to check that data/reports is relative to the url called to run the script, or perhaps change the path to be absolute. Are you able to check the owner of the folder it's trying to write to? Does the file already exist in the folder and not be writeable?

Answer (score 1):

First off, *chmod 777* is a hack and shouldn't really be used. If you're using apache, you are better off *chown*'ing the folder to the correct user.